# JQuery Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to drag item from one list to another list with clone. After stop dragging then i want to get id of parent div where it is dragged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using draggable and droppable, you can do i like this (Given that your ul's have the class `draggables`):

```
$("ul.draggables").droppable({
    drop: function() { alert($(this).parents("div:first").attr("id")) }
})
.find("li")
.draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5s5rt/1/

**Edit:** modified to find the first of the list's parents with type `div`, in case the div isn't it's immediate parent.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to use [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) as well as Draggable.

The following code provides an example of how to use Droppable.  It assumes the divs you want to allow items on have class name `someClassName`.  When you drag an item onto one of the divs, it pops up an alert box with the ID of the div you dropped your item onto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.someClassName").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            alert("You dropped an item onto a div with ID '" + event.target.id + "'");
        }
    });
});
```